# Firebase Cloud Messaging: navigator is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Firebase Cloud messaging and getting some errors I can't figure out the source for. This is the complete error log:

```
error - node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\esm\index.esm2017.js (1019:0) @ Component.WindowMessagingFactory [as instanceFactory]
error - ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at FirebaseProvider (./hooks/useFirebase.tsx:36:87)
null
error - node_modules\@firebase\messaging\dist\esm\index.esm2017.js (1167:0) @ eval
error - unhandledRejection: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1180:33) {
  code: 'messaging/unsupported-browser',
  customData: {}
}
null
```

So if I'm reading this correctly, there's two issues here:

ISSUE 1 - navigator is not defined -
it points at the file `index.esm2017.js`. I went to check the file and indeed I see 6 instances of `navigator` but at no place it is declared/imported. I of course don't generate that file, so not sure what I can do about it?
It points at my custom hook `useFirebase` which I guess invokes a method that requires that file. These are the two functions I've recently added to that custom hook file that are probably the source for that. This is the complete hook component:

```
type FirebaseContextProps = {
  auth: Auth | undefined;
  db: Firestore | undefined;
  storage: FirebaseStorage | undefined;
  functions: Functions | undefined;
  saveMessagingDeviceToken: (() => void) | undefined;
};

const FirebaseContext = createContext<FirebaseContextProps>({
  auth: undefined,
  db: undefined,
  storage: undefined,
  functions: undefined,
  saveMessagingDeviceToken: undefined,
});

export const FirebaseProvider = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const db = getFirestore(firebase_app);
  const storage = getStorage(firebase_app);
  const functions = getFunctions(firebase_app);
  const auth = getAuth(firebase_app);
  const messaging = getMessaging(firebase_app);

  // Saves the messaging device token to Cloud Firestore.
  async function saveMessagingDeviceToken() {
    if (!auth.currentUser) return;
    try {
      const currentToken = await getToken(getMessaging(firebase_app));
      if (currentToken) {
        console.log("Got FCM device token:", currentToken);
        // Saving the Device Token to Cloud Firestore.
        const tokenRef = doc(db, "fcm_tokens", currentToken);
        await setDoc(tokenRef, { uid: auth.currentUser.uid });

        // This will fire when a message is received while the app is in the foreground.
        // When the app is in the background, firebase-messaging-sw.js will receive the message instead.
        onMessage(messaging, (message) => {
          console.log(
            "New foreground notification from Firebase Messaging!",
            message.notification
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Need to request permissions to show notifications.
        requestNotificationsPermissions();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Unable to get messaging token.", error);
    }
  }

  // Requests permissions to show notifications.
  async function requestNotificationsPermissions() {
    console.log("Requesting notifications permission...");
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();

    if (permission === "granted") {
      console.log("Notification permission granted.");
      // Notification permission granted.
      await saveMessagingDeviceToken();
    } else {
      console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.");
    }
  }

  return (
    <FirebaseContext.Provider
      value={{ auth, db, storage, functions, saveMessagingDeviceToken }}
    >
      {children}
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function useFirebase() {
  return useContext(FirebaseContext);
}
```

ISSUE 2: Unsupported browser. This happens both on Chrome and on Brave (with `Use Google services for push messaging` enabled). In both instances, it's when running on localhost.

Comment: `navigator` is a `Navigator` that is available in all browsers. there is a problem with the environment in which you run the code or are in a sandbox (worker)